# Android: setReatinInstance(true) not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to retain fragment when configuration changes but even after using setRetainInstace(true), onDestroy() is called with screen rotation

Here is my fragment code:

```
public class HelloMoonFragment extends Fragment{

    private Button mPlay;
    private Button mStop;
    private Button mPause;
    private AudioPlayer mPlayer = new AudioPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, null);

        mPlay = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_playButton);
        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPlayer.play(view.getContext());
            }
        });

        mStop = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_stopButton);
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        });

        mPause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_pauseButton);
        mPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mPlayer.playpause();
                }catch (IllegalStateException | NullPointerException ex){
                    mPlayer.play(getActivity());
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ikkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.i("HEYEE", "NOOO");
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

and here is my layout xml file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/helloMoonFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:name="com.github.domain.hellomoon.HelloMoonFragment">

</fragment>
```

Why onDestroy() is called on each rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDestroy() is not going to be called but in your example, it is:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ikkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.i("HEYEE", "NOOO");
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
```

OnDestroy!=onDestroyView

onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).

onDestroyView Called when the view previously created by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has been detached from the fragment

Answer (score 1):

This is as designed. `onDestroyView()` will be called on a configuration change regardless of the `setRetainInstance()` flag. However, `onDestroy()` will not be called.

The reason for this is that the `Activity` in which the fragment is hosted may still be destroyed and re-created -- therefore, any `View` references in your `Fragment` will still be holding a reference to that now-dead `Activity`. So the expected behavior is that any instance state, running tasks, etc. can continue on properly during a configuration change; however, you are still responsible for releasing your `View` references and re-creating them in `onCreateView()`.